# How to force npm bin -g to print only the path

Tags: bash, npm, output

### Task

I want to use the path returned by `npm bin -g` in a script.

### Problem

`npm bin -g` returns the path then ***also*** prints to a new line that it isn't part of PATH env variable:

```
/home/username/.npm-global/bin
(not in PATH env variable)
```

To make it even more random, sometimes it prints this upgrade notice too:

```
 ╭─────────────────────────────────────╮
 │                                     │
 │   Update available 5.3.0 → 5.6.0    │
 │     Run npm i -g npm to update      │
 │                                     │
 ╰─────────────────────────────────────╯
```

These cause an error message in my script and halts its execution.

[image: Popup error message. Nothing happens until you OK this.]

### What have I tried

I tried to process only the first line of the output with `npm bin -g | head -n 1` but the second line still persists. I even tried `npm bin -g > /dev/null` but that made ***only*** the path go away, I still have the notice. What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### tl;dr

Use `npm bin -g 2> /dev/null`

### Explanation

The notice is printed to stderr. You need to redirect that to `/dev/null` with `2>`.

If you check out the [implementation of the `npm bin` command](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/v5.6.0/lib/bin.js):

```js
function bin (args, silent, cb) {
  if (typeof cb !== 'function') {
    cb = silent
    silent = false
  }
  var b = npm.bin
  var PATH = osenv.path()

  if (!silent) output(b)
  process.nextTick(cb.bind(this, null, b))

  if (npm.config.get('global') && PATH.indexOf(b) === -1) {
    npm.config.get('logstream').write('(not in PATH env variable)\n')
  }
}
```

You can see that in the end it checks if the path is in the PATH and if not, then **prints the message to `logstream`**. `logstream` comes from `npm.config`. If you check the defaults for that, you can see in [this line](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/v5.6.0/lib/config/defaults.js#L173), that it uses stderr:

```
logstream: process.stderr,
```

That is the reason why getting the first line only didn't worked, there were no second line. Also, `> /dev/null` redirected stdout, so you left only with the message from stderr. You can redirect stderr with `2>`.

Comment: This also means that you don't actually have to do anything special in the script to use the path. `ls -l "$(npm bin -g)"` works just fine, though it will continue to show warnings on screen.

Comment: @thatotherguy The script runs on startup, and because there is something on stderr it popups an error message that needs to be OKd to proceed. I didn't knew this until I found the solution.

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard of that behavior. Failing error codes definitely, but not just stderr. Which startup system is this?

Comment: @thatotherguy It [looked like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RMYh.jpg). Happens after login. This was the code at the end of `~/.profile`: `export PATH=$(npm bin -g):$PATH`. I know I can hard code it, but this is for dev laptops, the global pacakges folder path can change so it need to be dynamic.